# How to use Base Class properties on a generic type T that extends Base Class

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript-generics

Sorry if my english is bad, I'll try to explain with the code.

The code is being made with Typescript in the NestJs framework in order to abstract some repetitive functions

I have a base interface like this:

```
export interface EntityBaseInterface {
  id: string;
  createdAt: string;
}
```

And I was trying to use it in a generic service that receives a type that extends the base interface:

```
export abstract class GenericService<T extends EntityBaseInterface> {
  a: T = { id: 'asd', createdAt: 'now'}
}
```

But the generic class does not recognize the properties of the base class contained in T.

Error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ id: string; createdAt: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: string; createdAt: string; }'.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally can't use values for generics, they have to be function arguments provided elsewhere

So this thing should be eother in constructor, us `as unknown as`, or in `.init(t: T)`, or whatever

```
export interface EntityBaseInterface {
  id: string;
  createdAt: string;
}

export abstract class NonGenericService {
  a: EntityBaseInterface = { id: 'asd', createdAt: 'now'}
}

export abstract class GenericService<T extends EntityBaseInterface = EntityBaseInterface> {
  a!: T;
}
```